# Error installing scikit-learn on Apple M1: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, apple-m1

have problem install scikit-learn my device with macM1 chip
output are following

```
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.2.2.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [77 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-67.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.29.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.34-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
        Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
      Collecting scipy>=1.3.2
        Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [40 lines of output]
            The Meson build system
            Version: 1.1.0
            Source dir: /private/var/folders/8t/c7vp1svx67q7d6tfsbc_zrs80000gn/T/pip-install-4eup58s4/scipy_557714486dd74653a564911cc099d6bb
            Build dir: /private/var/folders/8t/c7vp1svx67q7d6tfsbc_zrs80000gn/T/pip-install-4eup58s4/scipy_557714486dd74653a564911cc099d6bb/.mesonpy-oy6xaeqf/build
            Build type: native build
            Project name: SciPy
            Project version: 1.10.1
            C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 13.0.0 "Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)")
            C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 711
            C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 13.0.0 "Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)")
            C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld64 711
            Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.34)
            Host machine cpu family: aarch64
            Host machine cpu: aarch64
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: YES
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: YES
            Library m found: YES
            Fortran compiler for the host machine: gfortran (gcc 13.1.0 "GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 13.1.0) 13.1.0")
            Fortran linker for the host machine: gfortran ld64 711
            Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
            Checking if "-Wl,--version-script" : links: NO
            Program cython found: YES (/private/var/folders/8t/c7vp1svx67q7d6tfsbc_zrs80000gn/T/pip-build-env-8q5edqdt/overlay/bin/cython)
            Program python found: YES (/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/pythonProject/bin/python)
            Found pkg-config: /opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config (0.29.2)
            Program pythran found: YES (/private/var/folders/8t/c7vp1svx67q7d6tfsbc_zrs80000gn/T/pip-build-env-8q5edqdt/overlay/bin/pythran)
            Run-time dependency threads found: YES
            Library npymath found: YES
            Library npyrandom found: YES
            Did not find CMake 'cmake'
            Found CMake: NO
            Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake)
            Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig and framework)
      
            ../../scipy/meson.build:134:7: ERROR: Dependency "OpenBLAS" not found, tried pkgconfig and framework
      
            A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/8t/c7vp1svx67q7d6tfsbc_zrs80000gn/T/pip-install-4eup58s4/scipy_557714486dd74653a564911cc099d6bb/.mesonpy-oy6xaeqf/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
            + meson setup --prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11 /private/var/folders/8t/c7vp1svx67q7d6tfsbc_zrs80000gn/T/pip-install-4eup58s4/scipy_557714486dd74653a564911cc099d6bb /private/var/folders/8t/c7vp1svx67q7d6tfsbc_zrs80000gn/T/pip-install-4eup58s4/scipy_557714486dd74653a564911cc099d6bb/.mesonpy-oy6xaeqf/build --native-file=/private/var/folders/8t/c7vp1svx67q7d6tfsbc_zrs80000gn/T/pip-install-4eup58s4/scipy_557714486dd74653a564911cc099d6bb/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed
      
      × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
      ╰─> See above for output.
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      
      [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1.2
      [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip

install using pip3 and everything online
```

Comment: It says `Did not find CMake`. Go and install CMake.

Comment: I've found it easier to run Scikit Learn and other Python libraries in virtual environments rather than installing them on my M1 Mac.

Comment: It seems you're in bad luck, and there is no binary wheel for your platform / OS combination. I do see a wheel listed for Python 3.10 on Arm (M1/2), but it has "macos_12_0" in its name, which I guess means (any) macOS 12, while the most recent OS on Macs is version 13. In which case, you may very well be stuck compiling from source. Which involves having compilers and utilities such as CMake installed; try `xcode-select --install` in a terminal (possibly with `sudo` prefixed), that may install all these utilities for you. Once that's installed, retry installing scikit-learn.

Comment: Alternatively, you may consider using Conda (with the miniconda installer), though my preference is to avoid Conda as much as possible (since, once things go wrong, it can be harder to debug what the issue is).